# Data service operation with parameters called from client library fails

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

The similar quetion already was asked here :

[ADO.Net Services service operation with parameters called from client library fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707881/ado-net-services-service-operation-with-parameters-called-from-client-library-fai)

The whole description of problem the ame as I have now. Only thing diffrent is what I pass all parameters in right way.

I have this opertaion method defined in data service:

```
[WebGet]
    public IQueryable<Equipment> GetCompanyEquips(int id)
    {
        return this.CurrentDataSource.GetCompanyEquips(id);
    }
```

And I can get result from it without any problem in my web browser:

http://localhost:51685/ITSServiceOData.svc/GetCompanyEquips?id=18

But when I' mtrying to get result in my client like this:

```
 var r = this.CreateQuery<Equipment>("GetCompanyEquips");

            r.AddQueryOption("id", CompanyId);

            r.ToArray();
```

I have following exception:

"An error occurred while processing this request."

Also I see in debugger what r.Query = "{http://localhost:51685/ITSServiceOData.svc/GetCompanyEquips}" and I suspect that something wrong here, because I don't see ?id=18 at the end here.

Also when I invoke method like this:

this.Execute("http://localhost:51685/ITSServiceOData.svc/GetCompanyEquips?id=18") - return contains empty enumeration (though in this case exception not raised) but when I invoke the same query string in browser it show expected result.

Also when I invoke in the similar way Method which haven't any params - all work fine. Please help! I've spent one whole day for this problem by searching in internet ant trying solve the issue but didn't find nothing wrong with my code!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AddQueryOption method returns a new instance of IQueryable. So you need to modify your code to do:

```
r = r.AddQueryOption("id", CompanyId);
```

One other thing: The client library does not support reading responses to service operations returning enumeration of primitive or complex types. So for this to work the Equipment type must be an entity type.

Comment: Thank you it's work. Still is the work around here to return not entity complex type through such operations, or only way here is to create another data service?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. The client library simply doesn't support parsing responses from service operations returning primitive or complex types (or enumerations of those). The "workaround" is to either return entity types from the service operation (sometimes possible, sometimes it's rather hard), or to parse such response yourself (the XML format is pretty easy to deal with).